# macOS 10.12 beta Unity crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, macos-sierra

I'm trying to run **Unity version 5.3.4** on **macOS 10.12 Sierra beta 2**. When I start Unity it crashes right off the bat. It used to work on beta 1. I've tried reinstalling Unity and it still won't work. Has anybody been able to get Unity to work on macOS Sierra?

Comment: While Unity can be considered as a tool used for programming or by programmers, this question is about getting it to start on a specific OS without crashing, and has nothing to do with programming as far as I can see. I've flagged a moderator to evaluate (and act upon) if it's appropriate to move it to Super User (another StackExchange website that might be better suited for this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have reached out to Unity3D regards macOS Sierra Beta 2 compatibility. They are aware of the issue..

> "We are aware of the issue and working to fix this."

..but could not give me an exact estimate as to when it would get fixed. I tried asking them "year, month, week, day?" and they weren't able to tell me.

> "Unfortunately, I don't know. I would guess within a week or two."

Please monitor at least this thread on Unity3D Forums:

https://community.unity.com/t5/Editor/Unity-crashing-on-macOS-Sierra-10-12-Dev-Preview-2/m-p/2644015#M286531

Clarification: Answered because Unity3D worked 100% a-ok with macOS Sierra Beta 1, and immediately stopped working when installed macOS Sierra Beta 2. Will edit answer when Unity3D have released a patch.

**UPDATE: Got this email from Unity from 19th July 2016:**

> "Thank you for your report. This is a known issue that has been fixed, please upgrade to Sierra beta 3."

Answer (score 1):

I've waited for update from Unity, and I installed all newer betas released. It didn't work.

But Sierra beta 3 just released today, install it and it solves the problem.